# Is it possible to change the data-type of a primary key column in SQL Azure?

Tags: primary-key, azure-sql-database

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I alter an existing Primary Key on SQL Azure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6937/how-can-i-alter-an-existing-primary-key-on-sql-azure)

OK, so say I have a table: 'Contact' and a primary key: 'ContactID'.

The primary key is an INT but I want to change it to a BIGINT.

In order to do this, I have to drop the primary key constraint.

In order to drop the constraint, I have to remove the clustered index.

But SQL Azure requires a clustered index on all tables at all times, so in order to remove the clustered index, I have to add another one on another field.

The problem is, I can't have more than one clustered index in a table.

So it seems like a catch-22: I can't remove the clustered index because there must be at least one, but I can't create another clustered index because there cannot be more than one.

So is it possible at all to change the data-type of a column in SQL Azure?

Comment: See this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/6937/2660